# v-menu how to make it not go over a navbar in vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

On the main page of vuetify we can see examples for the v-menu component, at this link

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#accessibility

If you click on any of the buttons to open the v-menu and then scroll up the page

[image: picture of v-menu going over]

You will see that the menu goes over the navigation bar at the top, not sure why this is built in to vuetify, but does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: i guess it's intended to be like that. If you really want to change the position then go for `position: relative` and do a `top: 50px` or something on that thing

Answer (score 2):

If you dig a bit into devTools, you can see that the `z-index` for `v-navbar` is 5, while the `z-index` for `v-menu` is 8. This is why the menu goes on top of navbar.

Obviously, you have two solutions: decrease the `v-menu`'s `z-index`, or increase `v-navbar`'s one. Decide, accordingly to your layout and needs.

Answer (score 1):

Vuetify is beautiful material design and developers sometimes find it hard to customize CSS.
However, Vuetify provides full access to customization using props, slot, etc.

The problem addressed can also be resolved by adding one prop.

```
<v-menu
  offset-y
>
```

Here `offset-y` offsets the menu from the bottom of the button

[Vuetify tutorial](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#offset-y)